# Behavior of memory barrier in Java

Tags: java, multithreading, memory-barriers, java-memory-model

After reading more blogs/articles etc, I am now really confused about the behavior of load/store before/after memory barrier.

Following are 2 quotes from Doug Lea in one of his clarification article about JMM, which are both very straighforward:

1. *Anything that was visible to thread A when it writes to volatile field f becomes visible to thread B when it reads f.*
2. *Note that it is important for both threads to access the same volatile variable in order to properly set up the happens-before relationship. It is not the case that everything visible to thread A when it writes volatile field f becomes visible to thread B after it reads volatile field g.*

But then when I looked into another [blog](http://mechanical-sympathy.blogspot.com/2011/07/memory-barriersfences.html) about memory barrier, I got these:

1. *A store barrier, “sfence” instruction on x86, forces all store instructions prior to the barrier to happen before the barrier and have the store buffers flushed to cache for the CPU on which it is issued.*
2. *A load barrier, “lfence” instruction on x86, forces all load instructions after the barrier to happen after the barrier and then wait on the load buffer to drain for that CPU.*

To me, Doug Lea's clarification is more strict than the other one: basically, it means if the load barrier and store barrier are on different monitors, the data consistency will not be guaranteed. But the later one means even if the barriers are on different monitors, the data consistency will be guaranteed. I am not sure if I understanding these 2 correctly and also I am not sure which of them is correct.

Considering the following codes:

```
  public class MemoryBarrier {
    volatile int i = 1, j = 2;
    int x;

    public void write() {
      x = 14; //W01
      i = 3;  //W02
    }

    public void read1() {
      if (i == 3) {  //R11
        if (x == 14) //R12
          System.out.println("Foo");
        else
          System.out.println("Bar");
      }
    }

    public void read2() {
      if (j == 2) {  //R21
        if (x == 14) //R22
          System.out.println("Foo");
        else
          System.out.println("Bar");
      }
    }
  }
```

Let's say we have 1 write thread TW1 first call the MemoryBarrier's write() method, then we have 2 reader threads TR1 and TR2 call MemoryBarrier's read1() and read2() method.Consider this program run on CPU which does not preserve ordering (x86 DO preserve ordering for such cases which is not the case), according to memory model, there will be a StoreStore barrier (let's say SB1) between W01/W02, as well as 2 LoadLoad barrier between R11/R12 and R21/R22 (let's say RB1 and RB2).

1. Since SB1 and RB1 are on same monitor *i*, so thread TR1 which calls *read1* should always see 14 on x, also "Foo" is always printed.
2. SB1 and RB2 are on different monitors, if Doug Lea is correct, thread TR2 will not be guaranteed to see 14 on x, which means "Bar" may be printed occasionally. But if memory barrier runs like Martin Thompson described in the [blog](http://mechanical-sympathy.blogspot.com/2011/07/memory-barriersfences.html), the Store barrier will push all data to main memory and Load barrier will pull all data from main memory to cache/buffer, then TR2 will also be guaranteed to see 14 on x.

I am not sure which one is correct, or both of them are but what Martin Thompson described is just for x86 architecture. JMM does not guarantee change to x is visible to TR2 but x86 implementation does.

Thanks~

Comment: You shouldn't care about memory barriers on x86. The semantics of Java and the Java Memory Model are defined on an _abstract machine_. That's the only thing that matters. The Java runtime takes care, that the guarantees made by the _abstract machine_ are fulfilled during runtime.

Comment: As a matter of fact the x86 semantics (including the cache coherency) are stronger than what the jmm demands, but there's no reason for you to care about any of that if you're not working on a java runtime for x86 as nosid correctly points out.

Comment: Your concern is valid. It is /possible/ that reader 2 would print Bar. However, unless the reader threads had previously interacted with the memory barrier class and cached the value of x, reader 2 will print foo because it will be accessing x for the first time. The interaction with write means the change to x will be visible. Perhaps a more interesting test is to have read1 and read2 execute both before and after W1.

Comment: `CountDownLatch` introduces an additional synchronization. So, if you use `CountDownLatch` to make sure, that `read2` is executed after `write`, then `read2` will always print `"Foo"`.

Comment: @asticx: The answer is: `"Bar"` is obviously possible, if there is no synchronization between `write` and `read2`, and it is not possible, if there is a synchronization. I guess that's not what you are interested in. So, please provide more information what you really want to know.

Comment: @nosid What Martin Thompson described in the blog are slightly different with Doug Lea's clarification as well as JMM happens-before principle, which I am a little confused. I guess it's just for x86 implementation, not a JMM thing. BTW. very good catch on CountDownLatch.

Comment: I don't think `sfence` flushes the store buffers to cache. Peterson/Decker synchronization needs `mfence`.

Answer (score 19):

Doug Lea is right. You can find the relevant part in section [§17.4.4](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-17.html#jls-17.4.4) of the *Java Language Specification*:

> **[§17.4.4 Synchronization Order](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-17.html#jls-17.4.4)**
>
> [..] A write to a volatile variable *v* (§8.3.1.4) *synchronizes-with* all subsequent reads of *v* by any thread (where "subsequent" is defined according to the synchronization order). [..]

The memory model of the *concrete machine* doesn't matter, because the semantics of the Java Programming Language are defined in terms of an *abstract machine* -- independent of the *concrete machine*. It's the responsibility of the Java runtime environment to execute the code in such a way, that it complies with the guarantees given by the *Java Language Specification*.

---

**Regarding the actual question:**

- If there is no further synchronization, the method `read2` can print `"Bar"`, because `read2` can be executed before `write`.
- If there is an additional synchronization with a `CountDownLatch` to make sure that `read2` is executed *after* `write`, then method `read2` will never print `"Bar"`, because the synchronization with `CountDownLatch` removes the *data race* on `x`.

---

**Independent volatile variables:**

Does it make sense, that a write to a volatile variable does not synchronize-with a read of any other volatile variable?

Yes, it makes sense. If two threads need to interact with each other, they usually have to use the same `volatile` variable in order to exchange information. On the other hand, if a thread uses a volatile variable without a need for interacting with all other threads, we don't want to pay the cost for a memory barrier.

It is actually important in practice. Let's make an example. The following class uses a volatile member variable:

```
class Int {
    public volatile int value;
    public Int(int value) { this.value = value; }
}
```

Imagine this class is used only locally within a method. The JIT compiler can easily detect, that the object is only used within this method ([Escape analysis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Escape_analysis)).

```
public int deepThought() {
    return new Int(42).value;
}
```

With the above rule, the JIT compiler can remove all effects of the `volatile` reads and writes, because the `volatile` variable can not be accesses from any other thread.

This optimization actually exists in the Java JIT compiler:

- [src/share/vm/opto/memnode.cpp](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/icedtea/jdk7/hotspot/file/d9f0ed25f7ed/src/share/vm/opto/memnode.cpp#l2862)

Comment: For clarification, if `write` happened `read2`, chronologically with no additional synchronization, could `"Bar"` still be printed?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis I think no, `14` can be read from `x` only *after* (I mean, *happens-after* it was written there in `write`, so only `Foo` will be printed.

Comment: @AlexeyMalev Yeah, but, before that, it reads `j`, not `i`, so IMO the quote `1.` doesn't apply.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis: How can you tell (without additional synchronization) if `read2` happened chronologically after `write`?

Comment: Share a `FileOuputStream` and write a timestamp to it from each thread. (I don't think that would add any additional synchronization if that's what you were getting at.)

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis: Let's assume there is a way to find out if `write` happened before `read2`. Even in this case, the method `read2` might still print `"Bar"`.

Comment: Is the only reason for that the first quote from Doug? That because `j` is checked by the `read2` thread, rather than the other `volatile i`, it doesn't see the change to `x`?

Comment: @Sotirios The JMM just doesn't give you that guarantee yes, so it's up to luck (well compiler optimizations and which platform) what you see.  Not something that'll happen on x86, but there are other ISAs where giving the weaker guarantee allows for much more efficient code generation (ARMv8 for example)

Comment: @Voo I guess x86 provides stronger guarantee than JMM to make change to     x     is visible by     read2     thread. JMM itself does not guarantee this happening.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I understood the question is actually about volatile read/writes and its happens-before guarantees. Speaking of that part, I have only one thing to add to nosid's answer:

Volatile writes cannot be moved before normal writes, volatile reads cannot be moved after normal reads. That's why `read1()` and `read2()` results will be as nosid wrote.

Speaking about barriers - the defininition sounds fine for me, but the one thing that probably confused you is that these are things/tools/way to/mechanism (call it whatever you like) to implement behavior described in JMM in hotspot. When using Java, you should rely on JMM guarantees, not implementation details.