# If I do not synchronize the methods, what is happening in the background which is causing the app to run while console prints nothing?

Tags: java, multithreading, thread-safety, locking

I have a main class which has two threads. These two threads runs two methods defined in other class.

**WaitNotifyMain.java**

```
package com.practice.multithreading;

public class WaitNotifyMain {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        WaitNotify waitNotify = new WaitNotify();
        Thread t1 = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    waitNotify.produce();
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });

        // lambda expressions Java 8
        Thread t2 = new Thread(() -> {
            try {
                waitNotify.consume();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        });

        t1.start();
        t2.start();

        try {
            t1.join();
            t2.join();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


    }

}
```

**WaitNotify.java**

```
package com.practice.multithreading;

import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.List;

public class WaitNotify {


    /*created an object of linkedlist without Polymorphism  as we require 
    removeFIrst() method which is specific to the linkedList class*/
    private LinkedList<Integer> list = new LinkedList<Integer>();

    private final int LIMIT=10;

    public void produce() throws InterruptedException{
        int value = 0;
        while(true) {

            while(list.size()!=LIMIT) {
            list.add(value++);
            System.out.println("Added an element");

            }

        }

    }

    public void consume() throws InterruptedException{

        while(true) {
            while(!list.isEmpty()) {
                System.out.print("List size :"+list.size());
                int value = list.removeFirst();
                System.out.println("; value is: " +value);

            }

        }
    }
}
```

**Output**

```
Added an element
Added an element
Added an element
Added an element
Added an element
Added an element
Added an element
Added an element
Added an element
Added an element
List size :1Added an element
; value is: 0
List size :10Added an element
; value is: 1
List size :10Added an element
; value is: 2
List size :10Added an element
; value is: 3
List size :10Added an element
; value is: 4
List size :10Added an element
; value is: 5
List size :10Added an element
; value is: 6
List size :10Added an element
; value is: 7
List size :10Added an element
; value is: 8
List size :10Added an element
; value is: 9
List size :10Added an element
; value is: 10
List size :10Added an element
; value is: 11
List size :10Added an element
; value is: 12
List size :10; value is: 13
List size :10; value is: 14
List size :9; value is: 15
List size :8; value is: 16
List size :7; value is: 17
List size :6; value is: 18
List size :5; value is: 19
List size :4Added an element
Added an element
Added an element
Added an element
Added an element
Added an element
Added an element
Added an element
; value is: 20
List size :10; value is: 21
List size :10; value is: 22
List size :9; value is: 23
List size :8; value is: 24
List size :7; value is: 25
List size :6; value is: 26
List size :5; value is: 27
List size :4; value is: 28
List size :3; value is: 29
List size :2; value is: 30
List size :1; value is: 31
Added an element
Added an element
Added an element
Added an element
Added an element
Added an element
Added an element
Added an element
Added an element
Added an element
Added an element
List size :1Added an element
; value is: 32
List size :10Added an element
; value is: 33
List size :10Added an element
; value is: 34
List size :10Added an element
; value is: 35
List size :10Added an element
; value is: 36
List size :10; value is: 37
List size :10Added an element
Added an element
; value is: 38
List size :10Added an element
; value is: 39
List size :10Added an element
; value is: 40
List size :10Added an element
; value is: 41
List size :10Added an element
; value is: 42
List size :10Added an element
; value is: 43
List size :10Added an element
; value is: 44
List size :10Added an element
; value is: 45
List size :10Added an element
; value is: 46
List size :10Added an element
; value is: 47
List size :10Added an element
; value is: 48
List size :10Added an element
; value is: 49
List size :10Added an element
; value is: 50
List size :10Added an element
; value is: 51
List size :10Added an element
; value is: 52
List size :10Added an element
; value is: 53
List size :10Added an element
; value is: 54
List size :10Added an element
; value is: 55
List size :10Added an element
; value is: 56
List size :10Added an element
; value is: 57
List size :10Added an element
; value is: 58
List size :10Added an element
; value is: 59
List size :10Added an element
; value is: 60
List size :10Added an element
; value is: 61
List size :10Added an element
; value is: 62
List size :10Added an element
; value is: 63
List size :10Added an element
; value is: 64
List size :10Added an element
; value is: 65
List size :10Added an element
; value is: 66
List size :10Added an element
; value is: 67
List size :10Added an element
; value is: 68
List size :10Added an element
; value is: 69
List size :10Added an element
; value is: 70
List size :10Added an element
; value is: 71
List size :10Added an element
; value is: 72
List size :10Added an element
; value is: 73
List size :10Added an element
; value is: 74
List size :10Added an element
; value is: 75
List size :10Added an element
; value is: 76
List size :10Added an element
; value is: 77
List size :10Added an element
; value is: 78
List size :10Added an element
; value is: 79
List size :10Added an element
; value is: 80
List size :10Added an element
; value is: 81
List size :10Added an element
; value is: 82
List size :10Added an element
; value is: 83
List size :10Added an element
; value is: 84
List size :10Added an element
; value is: 85
List size :10Added an element
; value is: 86
List size :10Added an element
; value is: 87
List size :10Added an element
; value is: 88
List size :10Added an element
; value is: 89
List size :10Added an element
; value is: 90
List size :10Added an element
; value is: 91
List size :10Added an element
; value is: 92
List size :10Added an element
; value is: 93
List size :10Added an element
; value is: 94
List size :10Added an element
; value is: 95
List size :10; value is: 96
List size :10; value is: 97
List size :9; value is: 98
List size :8; value is: 99
List size :7Added an element
Added an element
Added an element
Added an element
Added an element
; value is: 100
List size :10; value is: 101
List size :9; value is: 102
List size :8; value is: 103
List size :7; value is: 104
List size :6; value is: 105
List size :5; value is: 106
List size :4; value is: 107
List size :3; value is: 108
List size :2; value is: 109
List size :1; value is: 110

>>>>>>>after this nothing in console<<<<<<<<<<<<<
```

I understand that as it is not being synchronized it is not working as expected and i am getting diff outputs each time i run.

But my question is why the console shows my app is till running ,while i do not see any output in the console.

Can someone explain this behavior?

**I have tried out few more things, if put `Thread.sleep()` inside the outer loops then it keeps on printing in the console infinitely, and if i put `syso` in the outside loops then also i get output in the console indefinitely.**

What is this weird behavior.

Comment: I do not fully understand what you expect? to see more output or that your program terminates?

Comment: Also, is there a reason you have those outer infinite loops? Those don't seem necessary

Comment: I want to know what is happening in the background, due to which the program keeps on running while there is no output in the console.Those outer infinite loops will be used when i use `wait()` and `notify()`, but I was trying to understand how `threads` work by removing `snychornized locks` , `wait` and `notify`

Comment: Yes , I was expecting the program to keep on running along with console logs...it won t terminate I understand that. See, if i remove the condition of `list.size()!=LIMIT`  then it keeps on printing in the console infinetly. I want to know how adding just the condition makes the program run without the logs in the console. Pls explain...I am trying to learn multi threading...

Answer (score 2):

Add output in both `while(true)` loops, and you will see that one of the threads is stucked, probably the other thread is not getting the quantum time.

Comment: Yes, with `syso` in outer loops, it keeps on printing them  and in between i can see the `syso` of inner loops as  well. But without the outer `syso` the program seems to be hanged. I have added few more observations in the question, pls do check out.

Answer (score 1):

The JVM will, at some point, [cache](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34677691/10678955) the size of the list - which is the basis for `list.size()` and `list.isEmpty()` - in each thread, for as long as it can.

Without any `synchronized` block, "as long as it can" will be indefinitely.

If the producer is not synchronized, at some point it will cache `list.size() == 10`, and won't enter the inner loop, and won't produce any new values for the consumer to consume.

If the consumer is not synchronized, at some point it will cache `list.size() == 0`, and won't enter the inner loop, and won't clear space from the list to allow the producer to produce.

So in fact, you will get this hang even if you `synchronized` only the producer or only the consumer.

When you add something like `Thread.sleep()` or `System.out.println()`, you're asking the JVM to perform an operation that's essentially "external", which causes the JVM to refresh its cached values for this thread.

Comment: Okay I understand that, but whats up with my observations  which i have added in bold in my question, the behavior changes when `Thread.sleep()` is used, when some console.logs are used on the outer loops. Why the hang is not consistent....